# Changing json array field to string

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jhipster

I have a spring boot application which connects to a existing database (jhipster gateway) in order to manipulate the database to insert user inside it. So far it works I can connect to my database and insert a user if i give one property hardcoded the Authority property of a user. But I want to send this over json and not give a hardcoded one.

this is my json request (only relevant part):

```
"activated": true,
        "authorities": [
            "ROLE_ADMIN"
        ]
```

this is my user entity which I use to save my user:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
public class Users implements Serializable  {

private String authorities;

    public String getAuthorities() {
        return authorities;
        }

    public void setAuthorities(String authorities) {
        this.authorities = authorities;
    }
}
```

this is my save method:

```
public void addUser(@RequestBody Users user){
        userService.saveUser(user);
        Authority authority = new Authority();
        authority.setUserId(user.getId());
        authority.setName(user.getAuthorities());
        authorityService.saveAuthority(authority);
    }
```

I have a Authority class because authority connected with the user is saved on a joined table which also already exists:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user_authority")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Authority implements Serializable {

@Id
    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private Long userId;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "authority_name")
    private String
            name ;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUserId(Long userId) {
        this.userId = userId;
    }
}
```

the error I am getting is MissmatchedInputException, I know it is caused because I have authorities saved as a string in my code and sending a array through json.

```
deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `java.lang.String` out of START_ARRAY token
```

But if I change authorities to array I am getting this error:

```
Unknown column 'authorities' in 'field list'
```

Inside my user class. I am kinda confused on how to fix this. Is it possible to convert my jsonarray to a single value while sending?

Comment: You currenty save authority as a `String`, which is wrong. The `User` Class should have a  `Authority` object in it, with a `@ManyToMany` relationship, or whatever would be needed on the project. Still this way of saving it as a `String` is not correct.

Comment: Check this : https://attacomsian.com/blog/spring-data-jpa-many-to-many-mapping